# Python Pandas Multi-index Column: Set first level of header column as index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe with multi-index column headers that looks like this:

[image]

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `stack` and `swaplevel`:

```
>>> df
            A        B      
            1  2  3  1  2  3
11/12/2021  1  2  3  4  5  6

>>> df.stack(level=0).swaplevel()
              1  2  3
A 11/12/2021  1  2  3
B 11/12/2021  4  5  6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.unstack(level=0).unstack(level=1)
```

**output:**

```
                 1     2     3
A 2021-12-11  52.3  64.9  86.8
B 2021-12-11  32.3  12.6  14.7
```